# Using Command-W or Control-W to close a Frame

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a wx.Frame subclass that the user should be able to close by pressing Command-W (on OS X) or Control-W (on Windows). My code looks like

```
def MyWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.handle_key)
        # ...

    def handle_key(self, event):
        if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_CONTROL_W:
            self.Destroy()
```

Under Windows, `handle_key` does nothing until I have focused the `Frame` by clicking in it. After that, pressing a key triggers `handle_key`, but the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> trigger separate invocations of the function so the conditional is never satisfied.

Under OS X, `handle_key` is never called for any keypress, not even after I click within the `Frame` to set focus.

How can I implement this keypress handler so that

1. Its behavior is consistent across platforms, except for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> vs. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, and
2. the user can press the key combination at any time while the `Frame` is frontmost, regardless of which window actually has focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an AcceleratorTable instead of trying to catch the keypresses yourself. Here's a link to the docs:

- http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.AcceleratorTable-class.html

You may find this tutorial helpful too:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/07/02/wxpython-working-with-menus-toolbars-and-accelerators/

In your case, the code would look something like this:

```
exitId = wx.NewId()
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, id=exitId )

accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('W'), exitMenuItem.GetId()) ])
self.frame.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)
```

Answer (score 1):

The advice to use accelerator tables is a good one. But for completeness, if you really need to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd+W</kbd> your code should look like this:

```py
def handle_key(self, event):
    if event.GetKeyCode() == 'W' and event.GetModifiers() == wxMOD_CONTROL:
         # ... whatever ...
```

Notice that `wxMOD_CONTROL` is really <kbd>Cmd</kbd> under Mac (and you have a separate `wxMOD_RAW_CONTROL` which you can use if you really want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> under all platforms).

Answer (score 0):

**Using Command-W or Control-W to close a Frame**

Barebones example of using Ctrl-W to close a wx.Frame:

```
import wx
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tutorial", size=(500,500))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)


        #attach the key bind event to accellerator table
        randomId = wx.NewId()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onKeyCombo, id=randomId)
        accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('W'), randomId )])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)

    #method invoked on key press
    def onKeyCombo(self, event):
        print "You pressed CTRL+W!"
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Source: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators